# execute onclick action with function

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I have a page with several buttons(name SousMenu), all this buttons have onclick action.

Now I've create a main button to control all the button(idMenu). When the main button isn't checked, buttons aren't cheked.

```
if(document.getElementById(idMenu).checked == false) {  
    var x = document.getElementsByName(SousMenu);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].checked = false;
        x[i].onclick;
    }
}
```

Now I want to execute function for all buttons when the main button isn't checking, I've try something like `x[i].onclick` but it doesn't work..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` is a function, you have to call it using `()` :

`x[i].onclick();`

Comment: `x[i].click();` should work too.